The "oauth/consumer/enable_integration_as_bearer" path doesn't exist
I am trying to reset API but when I going to the path
Stores > Configuration > Services > OAuth > Consumer Settings > Allow OAuth Access Tokens to be used as standalone Bearer tokens
I did not find this option!
when I tried to enable it by running the following command:

php bin/magento config:set oauth/consumer/enable_integration_as_bearer
1

I get this error ( The "oauth/consumer/enable_integration_as_bearer" path doesn't exist. Verify and try again.)
magento 2.3.6

The option you are trying to find is not supported in the mentioned version - Magento 2.3.6. That is the reason you are getting this error and not finding it in the backend area.
Let me know the reason behind this option you are trying to set. I will guide the alternative way.

Thank you for the clarification. I am trying to connect magento 2.3.6 to app via API, but I getting error and I cannot figure out the problem.
As shown in the attached picture by edit apove

@HaiderMohammed, can you check the permission provided across this integration in the backend?
If it doesn't help, mail us at magento@tridhyatech.com with the details. Surely we will try to help it out.
